# Get first child of p inside span element

Tags: html, css

I need to get the first child of p elements (being created dynamically through JS and have same id). Basically I want to add a margin-top to the first p child element.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="exmkp" style="display:none">
      <span id="heading"></span>
        <p>......</p>
        <p>......</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `:first-of-type` pseudo class for that. It will always select the first paragraph inside `div#exmkp`, even when the paragraph isn't the first child.

```css
#exmkp p:first-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="exmkp">
  <span id="heading">Heading</span>
  <p>......</p>
  <p>......</p>
</div>
```

**Additional info**
If you want to select the first paragraph, but only when it also is the first child inside the div, you can use `#exmkp p:first-child`.

Answer (score 3):

nth-of-type pseudo selector can be used to target specific elements in a div 
try this :

```
div#exmkp p:nth-of-type(1) {
       margin-top : 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a rule for any child element like this

```
div#exmkp > p {
    margin-top : 10px;
}
```

and then revoke it for any element that's coming after another

```
div#exmkp > p + p {
    margin-top : 0;
}
```

this does only work for groups of paragraphs though (as in your example) – not, if they are interrupted by other elements. ([Working Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqOZrr))